# Configurar spacemacs para java (spring boot) ide

Tags: java, spring, emacs

Soy principiante usando spacemacs pero estoy tratando de aprender.
Soy un desarrollador java y he configurado spacemacs como un ide de java.

Mi configuration-layers es algo así:

```
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(javascript
     ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
     ;; Example of useful layers you may want to use right away.
     ;; Uncomment some layer names and press `SPC f e R' (Vim style) or
     ;; `M-m f e R' (Emacs style) to install them.
     ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
     auto-completion
     ;; better-defaults
     emacs-lisp
     git
     helm
     lsp
     markdown
     (multiple-cursors :variables multiple-cursors-backend 'mc)
     (plantuml :variables plantuml-jar-path "~/plantuml/plantuml.jar")
     org
     (shell :variables
             shell-default-height 30
             shell-default-position 'bottom)
     ;; spell-checking
     ;; syntax-checking
     version-control
     (java :variables java-backend 'lsp)
     dap
     treemacs)
```

Y mi user-config es algo así

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "Configuration for user code:
This function is called at the very end of Spacemacs startup, after layer
configuration.
Put your configuration code here, except for variables that should be set
before packages are loaded."
  (setq lombok-jar-path
        (expand-file-name
         "~/lombok/lombok.jar"
         )
        )

  (setq lsp-java-vmargs `(
                          "-noverify"
                          "-Xmx1G"
                          "-XX:+UseG1GC"
                          "-XX:+UseStringDeduplication"
                          ,(concat "-javaagent:" lombok-jar-path)
                          ,(concat "-Xbootclasspath/a:" lombok-jar-path)
                          "--add-opens"
                          "java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED"
                          "--add-opens"
                          "java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED"
                          "--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM"
                          )
        )
  )
```

Con esta configuración, puedo crear mis clases y escribir mi código correctamente, con el autocompleado y ayuda que ofrece la configuración, pero al momento de ejecutar el proyecto usando M-x dap-java-debug Recibo una excepción, exactamente la ClassNotFoundException.
Adjunto evidencia de ejecución
[image: error-result]

Quizás tenga que crear un launch.json como visual studio code pero no estoy seguro.

Alguien pudo ejecutar una app en spring boot con spacemacs?

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Up: por favor, no me digan que use un ide como Intellij o eclipse, mi intensión es aprender a usar emacs.

Comment: Hola. Recuerda añadir la traza de error completa (más completa, no nos resumas el error :P ) y algo más de información sobre cómo estás intentando usar dap. La pregunta actual (alguien pudo) tiene como respuesta sí, pero eso no te ayuda. Ver tu configuración y el error va a traer una mejor respuesta.

Comment: vale, gracias, lo actualizo de una mejor manera